# HTTP test server: print all client requests to stdout

Tags: java, http, curl, arduino, webserver

I need simple web server for debugging my application (Arduino web client, curl, etc.).

What is my idea:

I run command like

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Accept: application/json" -d '{"address":"192.168.200.3", \
  "title":"Abc" }' http://SERVER/xyz
```

to test webserver running at `http://SERVER:80`. This webserver write data + all http headers to standard terminal output.

It will be great for testing Arduino with Ethernet shield.

Is there any exiting product (for Linux)? I can write it in Java, but I do not want to reinvent the wheel...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I always use [nc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) (netcat) for this, in a style like:

```
nc -l -p 8080
```

It isn't really a "HTTP server" but only a dumb TCP server, but if you're mostly interested in seeing the client request and not necessarily serving back a proper HTTP response then it is good enough.

Comment: I started server using `nc -l 192.168.1.11 -p 80` command. After Arduino connect to "webserver" I see HTTP headers. But if Arduino send next HTTP request, `nc` do nothing. It will freeze on first Arduino connection. How is possible to solve it?

Comment: From the man page, it looks like you probably just want `nc -l 80`.

Comment: It depends on which `nc` version you have. Some want the -p, some don't.